# Mongodb Schema with parent_id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to do the schema of messages with answers. And i'm trying to do with parent_id but it doesn't work.

```
var messageSchema = new Schema({
_id : {type : String},
sender : { type : String},
reciver : {type : String},
text : {type : String},
answer:[{
    parent_id : _id,
    texto :{type:String}
}]
```

});

When i do the post with the answer always create a need random id and not the _id.
Thanks

Comment: Which `_id` do you want to assign to `parent_id`? Is it another message?

Comment: i would like that the _id would be the same that the parent_id

Comment: So you want the document ID (`_id`) to be stored as a property for all of its subdocuments in that answer array? What would be the purpose? It's possible but seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: But you will have one messages and various answers, and all this answers i need that they have the same parent_id

Comment: Are the answers more than the `texto` property? Since they will all be in the `answer` array of the same document can't they just access the document ID? If you are just looking for a convenience method you could use a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) for the subdocuments to avoid repeating the same data within the same document.